# import large list in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, list

I want to import list from another site in sharepoint 2010. What i'm doing so far is:

- save list as a template
- import list template to desired sharepoint site
- Create list based on imported list template

The problem is the import process is not always work. If stp file(list template file) is larger than 50mb, the import fail. Is there any way to override this limit setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set bigger max upload file limit in Central Administration in order to successfully upload your stp file.

Go to you Cental admin site and navigate to:
Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Web Applications
Click General Setting in ribbon, and choose general setting.

Once in general settings scroll to the bottom of the list and you will see the maximum upload size the default setting is 50mb this can be can set to a maximum size of 2047mb. If you try to go beyond this it does flag up and tell you that you have exceeded the Maximum size.